# Invalid characters in fileName, API response after sending Zip buffer

Tags: api, rust, zip

I'm trying to send the buffer of a zipped dir to an API that expects that, but I'm receiving a kind of weird response:

```json
{
    "message": "invalid characters in fileName: store\\\\blocks/\\nError: invalid characters in fileName: store\\\\blocks/\\n    at /usr/local/data/service/node_modules/yauzl/index.js:352:83\\n    at /usr/local/data/service/node_modules/yauzl/index.js:473:5\\n    at /usr/local/data/service/node_modules/fd-slicer/index.js:32:7\\n    at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:520:5)"
}
```

I'm imagining now it's something related to the final file name, but being a buffer I have no idea if it affects or even exists. But if it has, I would love to know how to change it, or if someone has already passed for something like this, how to solve it!

Some code here:

> Zip + send

```rust
// ? Zip the file, using the zip utils.
    let file: Vec<u8> = gzip::file::zip(path);

    // ? Send the file to the builder.
    match builder::link(file, token) {
        Ok(res) => {
            println!("{:?}", res.text());
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{:?}", e);
        }
    }
```

> API

```rust
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new(); // Create a new HTTP blocking client.
    return client // Setup the request.
        .post(Routes::assemble(Link)) // Define the endpoint.
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json, text/plain, */*") // Define the headers.
        .header(ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip") // More headers.
        .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, file.len()) // And more headers.
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream") // Guess what.
        .header(AUTHORIZATION, format!("Bearer {}", token)) // One more.
        .body(file) // And finally the body.
        .send(); // Just wrap it up and send it.
```

> Resumed zipping function

```rust
    let mut buf = Vec::new(); // Responsible for handling the buffer and the bytes in it.
    let mut cursor = Cursor::new(&mut buf); // Responsible for the cursor.
    let mut zip = ZipWriter::new(&mut cursor); // Responsible for the zip writer.
    let options = FileOptions::default()
        .compression_method(zip::CompressionMethod::Stored)
        .unix_permissions(0o755);
    let mut buffer = Vec::new();
    for entry in it {
        let path = entry.path(); // Get the file path
        if path.is_file() {
            zip.start_file(name.to_str().unwrap(), options).unwrap();
            let mut f = File::open(path).unwrap();
            f.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            zip.write_all(&*buffer).unwrap();
            buffer.clear();
        } else if name.as_os_str().len() != 0 {
            zip.add_directory(name.to_str().unwrap(), options).unwrap();
        }
    }

    zip.finish().unwrap(); // Close the file in the zip archive
    drop(zip);

    return buf;
```

Comment: Looking at the error message, it reports that the filenames you send contain escaped backward slashes (which it then escapes itself, leading to `\\\\`). Zip files don't use and implentations may not allow backward slashes at all, in the word of the origignal spec "All slashes MUST be forward slashes '/' as opposed to backwards slashes '\'". I assume `Path` normalises path separators and you're on windows, so it generates `\`-separated paths when serialising (when you call `name.as_str()`), which is not valid.

Comment: Looking at its bug tracker, this is probably [issue 253](https://github.com/zip-rs/zip/issues/253), and since the path-based APIs have seemingly not been un-deprecated I expect your only option is to perform the replacement by hand (just replace `\` by `/` after serialising paths to strings).

Comment: @Masklinn oh, that makes a lot of sense, and it's the solution, if you want just create an answer to mark as a solucion, and thank you for that! Heres the final snippet: 
`let mut p = str::replace(&name.to_str().unwrap(), "\\", "/"); if p.starts_with('/') { p.remove(0); }`